# undefined method for nil:NilClass while using where method with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

Here's a snippet of a code that is throwing an error:

```
<% count = 1 %>
<% exp = Expensestitle.where("expense_title_type_id = ?", 1) %>
<%= f.fields_for :aktiyary_items do |builder| %>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:5%;">
      <label><%= exp[count].name %></label>
      <%= builder.hidden_field :expensestitle_id, :class => 'form-control', :value => exp[count].id %>
    </td>
    <td style="width:1%">
      <%= builder.number_field :initial_amount, :class => 'form-control inputs', :value => 0.0, :autocomplete => 'off', :precision => 2, :step => 'any' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% count += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to display all the 'names' from a table (expensestitle) whose expense_title_type_id = 1. 
What I get is the following error:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

But if I replace the second line of code from above with:

```
<% exp = Expensestitle.all %>
```

it displays all the 'name' from expense_title_type_id of 1 and 2. I just want to limit the name to an id of 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Expensestitle.where("expense_title_type_id = ?", 1)` must be returning `[]`

Comment: The starting index of array `exp` is 0 not 1. So you should change `<% count = 1 %>` to `<% count = 0 %>`

Comment: @mainframer That's the solution. Thanks a lot mate. If you post it, I will mark it as answered.
And will you please also explain why was it working with .all . I'm still learning.